# How to add Command Prompt Here to a folder context menu in Windows 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, directory, command-line-interface

I am doing quite a bit of work at the command line and recently started having to do it on a Windows 2003 box.

I can't figure out how to add a Command Prompt Here to a folder context menu. And googling usually brings back methods for doing this in other OSes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [**install the XP Powertoy**](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx), or just add this to your registry

Create these 2 keys:

```
HKCR\Directory\shell\Open Command Prompt Here
HKCR\Directory\shell\Open Command Prompt Here\command
```

then set the default value for the \command key to **cmd.exe /k "cd %L"**

You can replace "Open Command Prompt Here" with whatever you want the right-click context menu to say.

Comment: You can also set the text for the context menu item in the default value for the "Open command prompt here" key. The advantage of this method is that you can put an ampersand before the letter you wish to be the access key, e.g. `Command &prompt here` will underline the `p`.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) , just right click on the Cmdhere.inf file and click install.

Answer (score 1):

I found it hard to believe that there isn't a CPH solution for Server 2003.  Did you try googling:

> "Command Prompt Here" "server 2003"

I quickly found this:

[**http://www.eknori.de/2008-07-13/elevated-command-prompt-here/**](http://www.eknori.de/2008-07-13/elevated-command-prompt-here/)

...and also, in another post someone talked about the XP Powertoy not working on some versions of 2003.